# Ffmpeg can't find codec parameters while converting images to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, image-processing

I tried to use ffmpeg both from repos and from github.
I tried this (also tried with `-c:v some_codec` ):

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 24 -pattern_type glob -i 'frame-*.jpg' -s WxH 'foo.avi'
ffmpeg version N-90232-g0645698ecc Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2)
  configuration: --disable-x86asm
  libavutil      56.  8.100 / 56.  8.100
  libavcodec     58. 13.102 / 58. 13.102
  libavformat    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavfilter     7. 12.100 /  7. 12.100
  libswscale      5.  0.102 /  5.  0.102
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
[image2 @ 0x5579541a5780] Could not open file : frame-*.jpg
[image2 @ 0x5579541a5780] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, image2, from 'frame-*.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
Output #0, avi, to 'foo.avi':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Input images named like that:

```
frame1.jpg frame2.jpg  ...
```

Comment: Show the actual `ffmpeg` command you used and the complete console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard done.

Comment: What are the input files named?  It's not finding them. Also, `-s WxH` is invalid: with `-s` you need to provide numbers, such as `-s 1280x720` (or omit `-s`).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard updated

Comment: @LordNeckbeard it seems it works now, I had to write frame* instead of frame-*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Typo

Your inputs are named `frame1.jpg`, `frame2.jpg`, etc, but you have a typo in your command.

Change `frame-*.jpg` to `frame*.jpg`.

## Zero padding

Because there is no zero padding in the file names (`frame1.jpg` vs `frame01.jpg`) the frame order may be incorrect when using the glob pattern. You can see the same effect using `ls` to view the files in the directory. To avoid this use the default sequence pattern instead:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i frame%01d.jpg output.avi
```

`-f image2` is not needed.

Unrelated, but building with `--disable-x86asm` is not recommended as it may cause slowness.